# Updating the data in django template by sending data from the same template to view without reloading page

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Here is my submit button along with the code for ajax request

```
<button type="submit" onclick="fn()" />
<script> 
function fn()
{
$.ajax({  
                      url: '/',  
                      type: 'POST',
                      data: { code: 'code'},
                        success: function(response) {
                            result = JSON.parse(response); 
                            if (result.error) { 

                                alert(result.error_text);
                            } else {  // Success
                                    $('#output').show();
                                    document.getElementById('output-ans').innerHTML=result;
                                    print 'yes';

                                } 
                            }
                        }
                    });  
      }
</script>
```

In my django view, I wrote

```
if request.is_ajax():
    do_something()
```

But this doesnot seems to work. The request type is `POST` not the ajax one. Data is received correctly but I am not able to modify the earlier template because of this.

Please suggest some way to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

When using `POST` via AJAX you need to pass the CSRF token. If you don't, you will get an `HTTP 403` (Forbidden):

```
function fn() {
    $.ajax({  
        url: "/",  
        type: "POST",
        data: { 
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}",
            "code": "code"
        },
        success: function(response) {
            result = JSON.parse(response); 
            if (result.error) { 
                alert(result.error_text);
            } else {  // Success
                $('#output').show();
                document.getElementById('output-ans').innerHTML=result;
                print 'yes';    
            } 
        }
    });  
}
```

That may be the reason your code is not reaching this part:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    do_something()
```

Check your console log

Comment: In the function call  `fn()`, even if I place an `alert()` in the starting, nothing happens. Additionally, I am getting all the data by `POST` but I do not know the reason for this so I think there is no 403 error.

Comment: If I remove `request.is_ajax()` , through `POST` data is being received to view.